# How do I find out if the currently logged-in user is on the domain?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried hitting this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Environment.UserDomainName: " + Environment.UserDomainName);
Console.WriteLine("Environment.UserName: " + Environment.UserName);
```

and when you are logged into the domain `Environment.UserDomainName` does return the proper value, but when not, it just returns the name of the computer.

So is there a good way to test if the current user is logged into a domain?

Comment: I can't reproduce. I logged in to my computer with my `domain\username` login. When I output `Environment.UserDomainName`, I get the domain name I used to log in. Are you sure you're logged in to the domain?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
    private bool IsUserInDomain()
    {
        var prefix = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[0].ToUpperInvariant();
        if (prefix != Environment.MachineName.ToUpperInvariant())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It checks the current logged in user's *"domain"* with the current computername. They are different if the user is not a local user.